# Angular2 - make *ngFor with conditional collection

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I need to make a conditional collection depending on the current value of the parent *ngFor.

`g.id` is a grid id and `c.idgrid` represents the relation between the arrays `cols` and `grids`.

How can I make this work with *ngFor?

```
//arrays

grids: Array<{ title: string, id: any }>;
cols: Array<{ name: string, idgrid: any }>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public acc: AccountService) {
    this.grids = [
        { title: 'Informações', id: 1 },
        { title: 'E-mails', id: 2 },
        { title: 'Contas Relacionadas', id: 3 },
        { title: 'Endereços', id: 4 },
        { title: 'Amostras', id: 5 },
        { title: 'Atividades', id: 6 }
    ];    
    this.cols = [
        { name: 'Ordem', idgrid: 1 },
        { name: 'Informação', idgrid: 1 },
        { name: 'Valor', idgrid: 1 },
        { name: 'Unidade de medida', idgrid: 1 },
        { name: 'Obrigatório', idgrid: 1 },
        { name: 'Tipo de e-mail', idgrid: 2 },
        { name: 'E-mail', idgrid: 2 },
        { name: 'Relação', idgrid: 3 },
        { name: 'Conta', idgrid: 3 },
        { name: 'Ativo?', idgrid: 3 },
        { name: 'Tipo de endereço', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Endereço', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Complemento', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'CEP', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Bairro', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Cidade', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Estado', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'País', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Latitude', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Longitude', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'Observação', idgrid: 4 },
        { name: 'ID', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Nº amostra', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Tipo de Amostra', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Conta', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Conta Relacionada', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Identificação', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Data da Coleta', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Situação da Amostra', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Parecer da Amostra', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Conclusão', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Centro de Serviço', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'Ativo?', idgrid: 5 },
        { name: 'ID', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Nº Atividade', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Tipo de Atividade', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Etapa Atual', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Conta', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Conta Relacionada', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Identificação', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Responsável', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Centro custo', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Área de Serviço', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Proprietário', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Execução', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Conclusão', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Finalizada', idgrid: 6 },
        { name: 'Ativo?', idgrid: 6 }
    ];    
}
```

View:

```
<ion-list *ngfor="let g of grids">
    <h1>{{g.title}}</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngfor="let c of cols[c.id] = g.id">ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly but maybe `<ng-container *ngIf="yourcondition"><th *ngFor="let c of cols[c.id]">ID</th></ng-container>`

Comment: The Angular team does not recommend using filters on the *ngFor but filtering the list in your code and presenting the filtered list to *ngFor. See this link down near the bottom in the section "No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe"  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-

If you still want to do it, have you seen this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#impure-flying-heroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach to solving your problem would be to write a custom filter. This could be the following function in your component:

```
getColumnsForGrid(id: number): Array<{ name: string, idgrid: any }> {
    return this.cols.filter(col => col.idgrid == id);
}
```

And in your template:

```
<ion-list *ngfor="let g of grids">
        <h1>{{g.title}}</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngfor="let col of getColumnsForGrid(g.id)">ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
```

You could also write a pipe that would do something similar.

Comment: not working, look for the result    Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-list'.
1. If 'ion-list' is an Angular component and it has 'ngforOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-list' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: <ion-list *ngfor="let g of grids">
            <h1>{{g.title}}</h1>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!--<th *ngfor="let col of getColumnsForGrid(g.id)">{{col.name}}</th>-->
                        </tr>
                        
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ion-list>

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe you have a typo somewhere. Make sure it says `*ngFor="let g of grids"`.

Comment: If `ngFor` is not know you probably didn't import `CommonModule` or `BrowserModule` into the module the component is part of.